# Using sed to append a line ignoring the white space for a specific line

Tags: sed, whitespace

So let's say I have a file

```
a            b           c
a            b             
a
```

and I want to append a line below of the line containing a b and c. So I write the command :

```
    sed -i '/s*a b c/a new line'
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong with the sed command that I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pattern is incorrect. Try this instead

```
sed -e '/a *b *c/a new line' file.txt
```

If you want to modify the original file in-place, add the `-i` flag. It would probably better to test it without it first though.

Comment: The trailing space star is superfluous, though.

Comment: It just means that if `c` is followed by something, that has to be a space character.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It means if there is a space, that's fine, and if there isn't, that's fine, too. It doesn't do anything to prevent matching if the following character isn't a space. More generally, specifying optional leading or trailing context for a match is useless (unless you specifically capture or otherwise handle just the matched part).

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the line (or unique part) of the first line, do:

```
sed -i '/^a[[:blank:]]*b[[:blank:]]*c$/a new line' file.txt
```

- `^a[[:blank:]]*` matches `a` at the start of the line followed by any number of whitespaces, similarly `b[[:blank:]]*` matches `b` followed by any number of whitespaces
- `c$` matches `c` at the end of the line

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
a            b           c
a
a
            b             
$ sed '/^a[[:blank:]]*b[[:blank:]]*c$/a new line' file.txt
a            b           c
new line
a            b             
a
```